# c# share a dictionary across projects

Tags: c#, dictionary, resourcedictionary

I have multiple apis that share a common project that builds a large dictionary. (3g+) The problem is if all of them are running concurrently, it runs the server out of memory. I know there is a way to build it once and share it, but I'm not sure how. I know there is a ResourceDictionary class, but I'm not sure how to use it if that is the answer. These are all console apps, so there is no wpf layer.

Comment: Have you considered ditching the dictionary and using a database instead?

Comment: The entire application is built on MS SQL. The db server is across the network from the application server. The amount of IO the dictionary saves makes the applications run many times faster. And, there are tens of thousands of transactions being processed by the apis, which need to be processed as close to instantly as possible.

Comment: Despite the fact that it uses a *remote* SQL Server database, this doesn't preclude you from having a *local* database (i.e. SQLite), that could be accessed from each of the applications, which would save you from having to deal with the complexities of actually sharing a `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` object between them.

Comment: I don't think hosting or data services would let me set up anything like that on one of the application servers.

Comment: Can I maybe create a keyed file in a common folder on the filesystem that has direct access like a dictionary?

Comment: The whole point of SQLite is that you don't have to set anything up on the server.  A SQLite database is just a file.  Even if you don't use the same file across all applications, the fact that you're not loading the entirety of your dataset into memory will reduce memory usage *dramatically*.  While it *might* not perform as well as having the entire dataset loaded into memory, performance should still be within the same order of magnitude, *and* you'll be using a *fraction* of the memory.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Assuming it's a read-only dictionary, you could create an assembly (i.e. DLL) project that loads it and include that in your other projects.</strike>

But you might be better off with some sort of database solution, such as [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/).

Comment: Each application would still need their own instance of the dictionary.  Sharing data across more than one `AppDomain` isn't what I'd consider "trivial".  I think your suggestion about using a database is by far the more valuable part of your answer.

Comment: @JoshuaShearer Thanks, I think you're right. I guess memory-mapped files would be another possible approach.

Comment: The whole point of creating the dictionary is to save db IO. The dictionary saves thousands of IO hits on the db. The entire application is built on top of MS SQL.